# Send email to IDN email ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I send email to non-Ascii email ID, for example I have adad@ÄÖß.com as emailID and when I try to send email to this emailID using

```
sendTo="adad@ÄÖß.com";
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(sendTo);
```

msg.To.Add(sendTo) throws an error saying "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.".

Did you guys face this ever?
Is this possible? if yes,
Any idea of how I can get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592703/convert-non-ascii-domain-to-smtp-compatible/1592753#1592753) its Jon Skeet doing the job once again.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Uri` has a config parameter for IDN support. I'm not sure if this affects `MailMessage`, too, or if there is an additional parameter for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this, it might help you:
[Convert non-ascii domain to SMTP compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592703/convert-non-ascii-domain-to-smtp-compatible)